# How to setup Windows 7 in Qemu on MAC?

Tags: osx-mavericks, qemu

I've installed quemu using homebrew . But in application folder there is no Qemu app. What to do? Im on osx Maverick.

Comment: qemu doesn't run natively on Mac, afaik - see http://wiki.qemu.org/Links

Answer (score 4):

`qemu` is a command line program, therefore all interactions with it have to be made using some shell.

Luckily you can create **`Automator.app`** little apps to open the VM after the setup of the OS is done, so you won't have to open the **`Terminal.app`** every time you start the VM.

So Open **`Terminal.app`** and...

#### Create a hard disk image:

```
qemu-img create -f raw -o size=20G Windoze7.img
```

#### Boot the ISO and Install:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom Windoze7x64sp1.iso -m 2048M -hda Windoze7.img
```

#### Boot the Windoze VM:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -hda Windoze7.raw
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a command line tool. By default it'll install into `/usr/local/bin/qemu-*`.

You probably want `qemu-system-x86_64`.